# How can I change production.rb in a node app that I'm deploying on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku, production

I'm asking because it seems like [How do I disable HTTPS on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15886900/how-do-i-disable-https-on-heroku) has a solution that I could use -- except I have no idea how to change `production.rb` for a node app. Where is this file? I understand it's some staging variable; how are those accessed?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think production.rb is relevant to node apps.
For node, you can set the NODE_ENV environment variable to 'production', 'development', 'testing' etc., via the Heroku dashboard (or heroku config:set NODE_ENV=value).
Then in your node.js app simply read the value of process.env.NODE_ENV to decide whether you are in production mode or not.